# How can I get 3 lists and variably merge them (python)

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists and I need to change their order according to what the user asks for, like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,12]
c = [13,14,15,16,17,18]
Result = [1,2,7,8,13,14,3,4,9,10,...,18]
```

In this case the user give me the number 2, I take two numbers from each list and make a fourth list.

After I go through the three lists, I need to put at the beginning of each new process a letter, like:

Final_list = [a,1,2,7,8,13,14,b,3,4,9,10,15,16,....]

Comment: I'm not following what the logic for the order of `result` should be here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the order of my choice"? Do you want the user to be able to specify the order?

Comment: What type of input are you taking in from the user?

Comment: You need to explain your logic

Comment: Yes, The user will give x number.
if this number is 3
a[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b[7,8,9,10,11,12]
Results [1,2,3,7,8,9,4,5,6,10,11,12]
But in the case with 3 lists

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do so:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]

number = 2

result = []
for i in range(0, len(data[0]), number):
    result += [num for sublist in data for num in sublist[i:i+number]]
print(result)  # [1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]
```

---

it can be simplified to a single list comprehension:

```
result = [num for i in range(0, len(data[0]), number) for sublist in data for num in sublist[i:i+number]]
print(result)
```

---

### Explanation

- We execute a loop that advances a certain number of steps each time, in this case 2 by 2.
- For each sub-list, we add 2 numbers from this sub-list.

The process is repeated until the end of the list is reached.

We can thus change the number of steps and the number of lists without any problem.

---

To better understand the list comprehension used, here is the version with for loops:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(data[0]), number):
    for sublist in data:
        for num in sublist[i:i+number]:
            result.append(num)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.extend()` along with a `for` loop that slices off `step` elements at a time for each list:

```py
step = int(input())

data = [
 [1,2,3,4,5,6],
 [7,8,9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16,17,18]
]

result = []
for i in range(0, len(data[0]), step):
    for sublist in data:
        result.extend(sublist[i:i+step])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
c = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

def round_robin(*lists, n=2):
    iters = cycle(map(iter, lists))
    while (chunk := list(islice(next(iters), n))):
        yield from chunk

print(list(round_robin(a, b, c)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]
>>>
```

This implementation will stop yielding values as soon as one of the iterators is exhausted (once the shortest list iterator is exhausted.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [7,8,9,10,11,12]
c = [13,14,15,16,17,18]

x = int(input('Enter Number:'))
# x = 3

mat = [a,b,c]
grouped = [[row[x*i:x*(i+1)] for i in range(len(row)//x)] for row in mat]
result = [k for col in zip(*grouped) for tup in col for k in tup]
```

For an idea of what's going on, it's helpful to see what `grouped` looks like. For `k=2,3`, it's

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
 [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]],
 [[13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18]]]
```

and

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
 [[13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]]
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I understand that you want to pick a given number off each list in turn. I'm not sure if the lists you give it are necessarily the same length, so perhaps a little generator that reacts sensibly to list exhaustion:

```
def pick_n_from_lists(lists, n):
    genset = [iter(a_list) for a_list in lists]
    data_left = True
    while data_left:
        data_left = False
        for g in genset:
            try:
                for _ in range(n):
                    yield next(g)
                data_left = True
            except StopIteration:
                continue

fred = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
jim = [1,2,3,4]
bob = [19,18,17,16,15,14]
print("output:", list(pick_n_from_lists((fred,jim,bob),3)))

output: [6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 19, 18, 17, 9, 10, 11, 4, 16, 15, 14, 12, 13, 14]
```